# Swift: whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is asked a lot but I've tried a lot of the other solutions on here and I can't seem to get it right.

So, I have a class that counts down, and at the end of the countdown a new view begins.

Here is the countdown class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CountdownController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!


var count = 3

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update() {
    if(count > 0) {
        countDownLabel.text = String(count--)
    }
    else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goestoMathTest", sender: self)

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: Actions

}
```

and the error that comes up after the MathTestController shows is:

```
2016-05-26 23:43:48.579 TraderMathTestiOS[18654:951105] Warning: Attempt to 
present <TraderMathTestiOS.MathTestController: 0x7fca824be7d0> on 
<TraderMathTestiOS.CountdownController: 0x7fca824b9d70> whose view is not in 
the window hierarchy!
```

**EDIT: So I tried another changing a few things and I think I narrowed down the issue. I changed the timer to be in viewDidLoad() and changed the repeats to 'false' and now MathTestController appears after 1 second with no warnings showing up. Here's the changed code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}


func update() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goestoMathTest", sender: self)

    if(count > 0) {
        countDownLabel.text = String(count--)
    }
    else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goestoMathTest", sender: self)

    }
}
```

I think the reason the error shows up is because the timer keeps repeating in the CountdownController even after MathTestController is called. Anybody know how to get my original functionality ( A timer that counts '3, 2, 1') without the error? Maybe I need to kill the timer somehow?

Comment: I suspect you cut off the beginning of that log message. Was there a line before it?

Comment: @kurtRevis You're right, I edited the error to show the full text

Comment: So once you start the timer. Which is after viewDidAppear in CountDownController, you are performing segue 3 times to showUp MathTestController. The moment you present MathTestController, CountDownController's view is not in windowHierarchy. and you are segueing from that. I think that's the problem.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha I've narrowed down the problem. Check my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this finally. For anyone wondering, if your timer repeats you need to invalidate it if you're starting a new view. Here's the fixed code:

```
class CountdownController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!
var timer = NSTimer()


var count = 3

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


func update() {

    if(count > 0) {
        countDownLabel.text = String(count--)
    }
    else {
        timer.invalidate()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goestoMathTest", sender: self)

    }
}
```